# Drop duplicate rows from DataFrame based on conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as follow:

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | True | 01/01/2022 00:00:00 |
| 002 | False | 03/01/2022 00:00:00 |
| 003 | True | 03/01/2022 00:00:00 |
| 001 | False | 01/01/2022 01:30:00 |
| 001 | True | 01/01/2022 01:30:00 |
| 002 | True | 03/01/2022 00:00:00 |
| 003 | True | 03/01/2022 00:30:00 |
| 004 | False | 03/01/2022 00:30:00 |
| 005 | False | 01/01/2022 00:00:00 |

There are some duplicate rows in the raw dataframe and I would like to remove duplicate rows based on following conditions:

- If there are **duplicate ids on the same date and same time**, **select a row with value "True"** (e.g., id = 002)
- If there are **duplicate ids with same value**, **select a row with the latest date and time** (e.g., id == 003)
- If there are **duplicate ids**, **select row with the latest date and time and select a row with value "True"** (e.g., id == 001)

Expected output:

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | True | 01/01/2022 01:30:00 |
| 002 | True | 03/01/2022 00:00:00 |
| 003 | True | 03/01/2022 00:30:00 |
| 004 | False | 03/01/2022 00:30:00 |
| 005 | False | 01/01/2022 00:00:00 |

Can somebody suggested me how to drop duplicates from dataframe based on above mentioned conditions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perhaps you just need to sort your dataframe prior to dropping duplicates.  Something like this:

```
output =    (
              df.sort_values(by=['date','value'], ascending=False)
                .drop_duplicates(subset='id')
                .sort_values(by='id')
)
```

print(output)

Output

```
   id  value                date
4   1   True 2022-01-01 01:30:00
5   2   True 2022-03-01 00:00:00
6   3   True 2022-03-01 00:30:00
7   4  False 2022-03-01 00:30:00
8   5  False 2022-01-01 00:00:00
```